# Design question on storing meteorological data on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, compression, database-design

We're using SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition.

We are measuring meteorological data from what we call MetMasts.
Basically this is a mast with lots of equipment; anemometers (for wind speed) at different positions on the mast, thermometers , and air pressure.
We measure every second.

And it takes up tooooo much disk space.
The next generation of this equipment will generate over 10 GB per year each. And we’re going to have more than 1000 of these.

The current table design looks a bit like this:

```
    CREATE TABLE #MetMast (
    MetMastID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1), 
    MetMastName NVARCHAR(100), 
    CountryID INT, 
    InstallDate DATE
)
    CREATE TABLE #MetMastData (
        MetMastDataID BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
        MetMastID INT NOT NULL,
        MeasuredAt DATETIME2(0) NOT NULL,
        Temperature REAL NULL,
        WindSpeedAt10m REAL NULL, 
        WindSpeedAt30m REAL NULL,
        AirPressure REAL NULL,
        OneHundredMoreColumns VARCHAR(200),
     CONSTRAINT PK_MetMastData PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        MetMastID ASC,
        MeasuredAt ASC
    ))
    WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = ROW) 
    -- ON a file group, with table partitioning
    ALTER TABLE #MetMastData WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT FK_MetMast_MetMastID FOREIGN KEY (#MetMast) REFERENCES #MetMast(MetMastID)
```

The data is write once, read many, many times.
We use it in our data warehouse, where a typical question would be; Count how many times there is a 2 m/s difference between WindSpeedAt10m and WindSpeedAt30m when the temperature is above 20 degrees, per MetMast.

```
SELECT MetMastId, COUNT_BIG(*) FROM #metMastData 
WHERE temperature>20 AND ABS(WindSpeedAt10m-WindSpeedAt30m) >2 
GROUP BY MetMastID
```

In the future a tiny bit of data loss will be accepted.
 
We’re talking lossy compression of data here. I know we will have to define an acceptable error for each of the fields, as in 1% if we measure with 10% accuracy.
It worked for sound files (MP3 is quite big), so it might work for us as well.

**But how is this done?

What table design should I go for? 

How do I get started with lossy compression of data in database tables?**

Best regards,

Henrik Staun Poulsen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each of your data points, consider the accuracy you need to store.

REAL takes up four bytes for each row. If you could drop all decimal places for WindSpeed, you could probably do with a tinyint (1 byte, 1-255). Given that you most likely need some precision, you could use a smallint instead and multiply the actual value by 100:

```
150,55 m/s = 15055
3,67 m/s = 367
```

This would save you two bytes per row and store some precision, though with a loss at some point. Since it seems you'll have quite a lot of these columns, a 2 byte saving per column would amount to quite a lot.

You've got an 8 byte bigint for your MetMastDataID. Is it necesary? Won't everything be queried by MetMastID and MeasuredAT? Dropping that will save you 8 bytes. It will however result in fragmentation since your clustered key will no longer be sequential, so defragmentation will be necessary. Since this sounds like an archival/OLAP system, that shouldn't be a big problem.

EDIT: I just realized you're not clustered on the MetMastDataID so fragmentation won't change from now. Question is then - do you ever use the MetMastDataID for anything?

Further - if you can avoid all variable length columns, that'll save you 2 bytes + 2 bytes per variable length column of record overhead, per row, not including the actual variable length data itself.

Comment: Hej Mark, Thank you very much for your reply, which is in tune with R. Kimball; put your fact on a diet. We have done that, as far as we can. But a lot of this data does not change very often; temperatures are only measured every 42 seconds. So there must be loads of room for improvement here.

Comment: You mention tempratures are only measured every 42 seconds - does that mean you only record data, overall, every 42nd second, or do you record other data on a lower interval, and thus save the same temperature value multiple times? In the case that you store a measurement every second, that means you'll have 41 identical values for the temperature - in which case implementing those columns as sparse would make sense. Every 42nd has a value while the remaining are NULL, indicating they're equal to the last measured value.

Comment: Btw, I see that you're from Aarhus as well - let me know if you're interested in arranging an offline look at this - free of charges of course. It's an interesting case, I'd love to take a more thorough look at it :)

Comment: Hi Mark, Yes that is an option we have been thinking about. We're a bit concerned about retrieving these data afterwards. The 42 is not a fixed number, it is just easy to explain the oversampling that way. Thank you for the offer for offline look. We're hosting the next sqlsug meeting, if you're a member, we can talk a bit more then. (unfortunately not much without an NDA)

Comment: I'm pretty sure i'll be at the sqlsug meeting, cya there then :)

Answer (score 1):

Lossy compression is based on human`s physical possibilities to determine difference by eye or ear. Examples are Mp3 or JPEG lossy compression. In your case such kind of lossy compression has no sense, because you operate with digits not with audio/video data.
To implement lossless comression you can use CLR function.Example is here:[http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/blob_compress.asp](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/blob_compress.aspx)x.

Comment: Hi Dalex, I realize now that we need to state our requirements for each field. But this should be possible. Wind is measured with an accuracy of +-5%, so it would be acceptable to add .5% if we improve the storage situation. Thank you the link, we might be able to use some of it.